# mocha fs.existsSync always failing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, fs

I am attempting to check if a file exists in my mocha test. I know for a fact that the file exists in the test folder(I am placing it there for simplicity while I try and get this to work). But no matter what I do, fs.existsSync always fails. Logger.startup() creates the file. Logger.getFilename() returns a value like 5-17-30-2013.log. I am new to mocha so have no clue if I am making a classic blunder. As far as I know I am using mocha synchronously. Thanks for all of the help.

Here is my Mocha Test script:

```
var logger = require('../logger');
var fs = require('fs');

describe("Logger", function () {
    it("Creates a file", function () {
        logger.startup();
        console.log(logger.getFilename());
        if (!fs.existsSync(logger.getFilename())) {
            throw ("Logging File Does Not Exist");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Better than the answer below, try using require('path').resolve(logger.getFilename()).  path.resolve returns an absolute path given a (possibly) relative filename.

Comment: Right now it is loading a file in the same directory(so all I need is the film file name), but I did try a absolute path for a while to no success either. Also, as a note, I can try and check if the file exists perfectly from the script logger by prepending "test/" to the fs exists sync call( but not in mocha)

Comment: The script being in the same directory does not mean that all you need  is the file name.  Do this, in the script that is having issues:

console.log('ls -l', path.resolve(logger.getFilename()));

which will print something like "ls -l /Users/jon/stuff/fn.txt".

In a shell, run the line printed.  Now you know for sure whether the file exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The currently [accepted self-answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18685299/1906307) explanation falls short. It says:

> Apearently fs looks at the root of the project, the package.json folder, and not realative to the file calling it, which I did not know.

Sure, but it's not happenstance or a quirk of the `fs` module. The `fs` module uses `process.cwd()` to interpret relative paths passed to it. Unless it is changed with `process.chdir()`, `process.cwd()` is the directory in which the current process has been started. Since `mocha` is usually launched from the root of a project, then in a `mocha` process, `process.cwd()` is usually going to be the root of the project. If `mocha` were launched from a different directory, then `process.cwd()` would have a different value.

The confusion may come from how the module system handles relative paths. A module name with a relative path will be interpreted relative to the `__dirname` of the current file. This may be a value different from `process.cwd()`.

Answer (score 0):

try using process.cwd() to determine the working directory fs.exists is running from

Comment: The folder defeniatly exists, see my above comment for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for **__dirname**, try to prepend it to the filename.

Documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Answer (score 0):

I followed @jjm and his advice on the program. After logging where it thought the file was, it turns out that it was looking in the folder "logger", not "logger/test" Apearently fs looks at the root of the project, the package.json folder, and not realative to the file calling it, which I did not know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fs.open(filepath, 'r', callback);`

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
describe("Logger", function () {
    it("Creates a file", function (done) {
        logger.startup();
        console.log(logger.getFilename());
        fs.readFile(logger.getFilename(), done);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please first read the other answers before you post, you probably then noticed the path was the actual problem and the answer you give is wrong. Also have a look at the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and how to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer